# Get Category list related to current page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i need to display the category list related to the current page (based on selected category in admin.) in wordpress site. i tried with get_the_category($post_id). But it's not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try get_the_terms() instead. It should return an array of cats. Wordpress considers categories a taxonomy, so specifying 'category' as the taxonomy type should do the trick.Hope this helps.

```
$array_of_cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
  foreach($array_of_cats as $key=> $value){
  //output as a list...
  }
```

Function reference [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).